# Add gift registry button in Product list view

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I'm using a plugin [Gift Registry](https://store.magenest.com/magento-2/gift-registry.html)
I want to add the Gift Registry button in my product list view. Right now the plugin only shows in the Product View Page. But we want to show it in the Product List View. But I keep getting an error of

[image]

I added this in the `Magento_Catalog/layout/default.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magenest\GiftRegistry\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.additem" as="additem" template="Magenest_GiftRegistry::item/configure/addto.phtml" after="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

It seems that it's throwing an error because the plugin is expecting an ID for the product page but since this is a product list so its not really targeting the exact product but a list. How can I fix this?

Update:

I tried to add this in the `Magento_Catalog/layut/catalog_category_view.xml` and added this code

[image]

As you can see the highlighted below is pointing to a block in `Magenest\GiftRegistry\Block\Product\View` but when running the site it's giving me this error

[image]

As seen here. It's pointing to the `magento-catalog/Block/Product/View` instead in `Magenest\GiftRegistry\Block\Product\View`. How do I let the layout loads the correct block?

Comment: step 1. You should extend from layout "vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml"

step 2. Then, referenceBlock has identifier  : as="product_list" and add your block in here.
Suppose:
<referenceBlock name="product_list" ifconfig="example/gift_registry/enabled">
     <block class="ClassA" name="gift__button-add" template="Example_Gift::list/button-add.phtml"/>
</referenceBlock>

step 3. note: ClassA need to extends class "\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Block"

Comment: @@ quite confusing, ...  
You should read layout "catalog_category_view.xml" to know more. :(( 
Hope, it will help you.

Comment: @NguyễnHoàngTuấn yeah a little confusing. If you can provide any tutorial that would be much appreciated

Comment: ok. pls wait me

Answer (score 0):

You can chose this way: 
step 1: Override layout & add new block in layout
[image]

step 2: Create class ButtonRegistry
[image]

note: This class need to extends Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Block because, it contain 2methods setProduct() & getProduct(). They will help you get data at template. You can extends AbstractProduct but not recommended. 
step 3: Override template of class "Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct"
[image]
In list.phtml, add code to render template "add-button-registry"
[image]

And here is regítry.phtml template 
[image]

Finally, this's our result 
[image]

Comment: Hope, this way can help you. :))